# Как правильно вывести картинки в сообщениях через IMAP?

Tags: php, imap

Добрый вечер, работаю с почтой по протоколу IMAP.
Когда отправлю сообщение из gmail с картинкой, то при просмотри сообщения, картинка не отображается, хотя остальное тело сообщения все корректно отображается.

Ниже видно, как отображается сообщение + скрин с консоли
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего отправляйте в `src` атрибуте полную ссылку на картинку на вашем сервере например `<img src="http://myserver.com/uploads/img.jpg">`